# SQL Server Reporting Services 2005, preview differs from deployed report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, preview

I created a Subreport in SSRS 2005 with a bar chart and a textbox above, just as a simple progress bar. I'll use it in a report to show a percentage.

In the Report preview it works fine and the progressbar looks like this:

[Preview](http://tinypic.com/r/6oep9y/6)

But when I the deploy the report on the report server I get this:
[Deployed Report](http://tinypic.com/r/dol7pi/6)

It's not really new to me, that sometimes the output in the preview differs from the server, but unfortunately I just can't find a solution for this issue.

Thx in advance

Comment: What are you using to create the report, BIDS or the Report Designer? Is there a difference between the SSRS version on the server and the version you are using for report authoring?

Comment: Did you check your progress bar in IE?

Comment: Did you also compare it against the PDF export version? I bet it's different there as well! I have the same issue. The report looks different in designer, on the web, and when exported as PDF. All three environments behave differently on SSRS. I am using 2005 version. Anyone come across a possible solution? And this happens regardless of browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are seeing is a browser issue.

The default css that SSRS outputs is very biased towards IE. (It doesn't play well with IE9 either)
This causes a lot of issues on browsers like firefox and safari.

If you really must get it to display that way, remember that SSRS does allow you to create custom rendering extensions(Would be too much effort to fix a small bug though).