# Show/hide columns ssrs not returning results

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to build an ssrs report where based on parameters will show/hide columns. In development environment using vs2008 previewing the data it works. After deploying to the development server it returns no results.

This is the expression I am using

```
=iif(Parameters!SampleReceiveDate.Value = "True", False, True)
```

What would cause this to return no results when in the development environment it works as expected. We have tried removing the rdl and the datasource from the development server and redeploying to no success.

Any and all help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the issue is browser based and that Chrome will not render the CSS correctly based on the information in this link [to previous question with same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239730/sql-server-reporting-services-2005-preview-differs-from-deployed-report)